# Make a bootable usb for an iso file greater than 4 GB?

Tags: kubuntu, format

How can I make the bootable USB for the greater ISO file, greater than 4 GB?
I tried a lot of programs like woeusb and startup creator.

[image]

Comment: @C.La Mosca which command I should write in uppercase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to make a bootable USB from an ISO file (Maybe a Windows installation ISO?) using WoeUSB, and the error message said that you can not copy the file `install.wim` in the the partition because the parameters by default in WoeUSB for the target filesystem (USB stick) are FAT32. That is what i saw in the link posted by you: [WoeUSB Installation failed ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Js7G4.png)

Now, from the man page of WoeUSB ([WoeUSB man page](https://www.mankier.com/1/woeusb)) the options

```
`--target-filesystem`
```

and

```
`--device`
```

will help you.

To accomplish the task you should type in the command line something like this:

```
sudo woeusb --target-filesystem NTFS --device /media/pathtothe/isofile.iso /dev/sdX
```

whith the option `--target-filesystem NTFS` you make possible copy into the USB files greater than 4GiB. In your case the `install.wim` file.

/dev/sdX is the target device (your USB stick unmounted). Change the X according to your needs.

That should work.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89138/discussion-on-answer-by-c-la-mosca-make-a-bootable-usb-for-an-iso-file-greater).

Comment: When in about 82% completion, I get the error: `ERROR: The command "dd if="${source_file}" bs="${dd_block_size}" skip="${i}" seek="${i}" of="${dest_file}" count=1 2> /dev/null" failed with exit status "1", program is prematurely aborted`. Any idea on how to address?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be running into the 4GB file size restriction when using FAT16/32 partitions.

Try wiping the USB stick and re-partitioning it at an ext4 partition on your USB stick (assuming your USB stick is /dev/USB0 ):

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/USB0
```

Comment: If UEFI, you have to have a FAT32 partition for UEFI boot. If BIOS boot you may need to use grub in separate /boot partition. Do your really need that large of an ISO, or can you add another partition with scripts to add changes you want?

Comment: I did format it to ntfs successfully. The problem is to write the ISO file, which is greater than 4GB.

Comment: @oldfred the size of the ISO file is 5.1 GB